# Why yield() and cond_resched() do not yield to another thread

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, pci-e

Why [riffa_driver.c yield() function](https://gist.github.com/promach/7716ee8addcaa33fda140d74d1ad94d6#file-riffa_driver-c-L746) does not yield to [chnl_send() thread](https://gist.github.com/promach/7716ee8addcaa33fda140d74d1ad94d6#file-riffa_driver-c-L883) ?

[image]

Comment: None of these function is *enforced* to switch to another CPU. As far as I remember, `cond_resched` just marks given point as possible to reschedule. It is up to the scheduler to switch the thread or not. As for `yield` its usage isn't recommended at all (see e.g. its [description](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L5050) in the sources).